# How to terminate a log in

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I'm wondering what I would need to do in order to terminate a login box if I was to put in the information wrong more than 3 times. The code below is how I am making the login box function. i seem to be miss informing you.. i am still brand new to C# and Still pretty new to Stackoverflow.

```
   public void Login()
   {
        if (user_box.Text == "1111" && Password_box.Text == "Master")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome Albert Einstein.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No User Input.");
        }
   }
```

Comment: Simply count the failures in a variable and when it reaches the limit, terminate the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   int count = 0;

   public void Login()
   {
      if(count <= 3)
      {
           if (user_box.Text == "1111" && Password_box.Text == "Master")
           {
                 MessageBox.Show("Welcome Albert Einstein.");
           }
           else
           {
                 MessageBox.Show("No User Input.");
                 count++;
           }
       }
       else
       {
            user_box.Enabled = false;
            Password_box.Enabled = false;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add counter for failures.

```
int failures = 0;    

if (user_box.Text == "1111" && Password_box.Text == "Master" && failures<=3)    

else {    
failures++;
```

Comment: And so how can i make it terminate itself based on add the counters?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a session variable and increment it every time the user gives wrong password and it gets 3. You can show him a message or block that user for sometime by updating a column in your database or do u r xustom code to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a count of failed login attempts somewhere. Probably in a database if you are expecting to have a lot of users. If you only have several users you could store the data in xml.

Then when a user tries to login you can do a check against the failed login list and see if there has been failed logins. If there has and there has already been three failed attemps then you can deny access.